# Flatpickr Datepicker has issues with keyboard accessibility and behavior when used inside bootstrap modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, modal-dialog, accessibility, flatpickr

Using Flatpickr Datepicker inside Bootstrap modal - focus on tab and selecting dates using keyboard arrow buttons not working anymore.

**REPRO LINK**
https://jsfiddle.net/pLxhn0d7/

**HTML**

```
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Use Datepicker</h4>
        <button type="button" class="cls close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body p-4">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="ac3" class="control-label">Select Date</label>
              <input type="text" id="ac3" name="ac3" class="form-control date" placeholder="Select date" required>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary waves-effect cls" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div><!-- /.modal -->

<article>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Select Date.." class=date>
</article>
<br><br>
<button  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#acon">
  Launch Modal
</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
const fp = flatpickr(".date", {
dateFormat:"d-m-Y"
});
```

**Environment details:**

- Flatpickr version used: 4.5.4
- Browser name and version: Google Chrome
    79.0.3945.130 (Official Build)
- OS and version: Windows 10 Pro 64-bit

Comment: fixed by adding option static:true

Comment: Is there a question in here bud? Also when I tab into the box and then press the arrow keys it works fine with the given fiddle (press down arrow key first). What do you need help with?

Comment: it works in the input box outside yes, but not in the one inside the modal. As I discovered an hour later, you need to set the 'static' option to true for it to work